# Define a crontab job containing wildcards (*) without expanding them

Tags: bash, cron

I need to install a new `crontab` which runs a script every 2 minutes. 
To do that, I should be writing the following in the `crontab` file:

```
*/2 * * * * cd /myDirectory/ && ./myScript.sh
```

I need to install this `crontab` command programmaticaly, using the same `myScript.sh`. I tried to do it like this:

```
crontab -l > ./currentcron              #save current crontab in file
echo ${FULL_CRONTAB} >> ./currentcron   #append my command
crontab ./currentcron                   #install new file
rm ./currentcron                        #remove temporary file
```

The logic works, but the problem is my `FULL_CRONTAB` variable. I have tried to define it like this:

```
FULL_CRONTAB="*/2 * * * * cd ${APPLICATION_DIRECTORY}/ && ./myScript.sh"
```

... but the string gets expanded because of `"` so the variable actually gets a full list of files in the folder instead of my target string that I should add to my crontab.

I've tried to use single quotes (`'`) instead, but nothing changes.

I've also tried to escape the `*` (e.g. `FULL_CRONTAB="\*/2 \* \* \* \* cd ${APPLICATION_DIRECTORY}/ && ./myScript.sh"`), but the variable contains the `\` and not just the `*` so it's not usable.

Feels like a basic question, but I'm not coming out of this: how can I get my `FULL_CRONTAB` defined knowing that I have to interpret `${APPLICATION_DIRECTORY}`, but that I don't want to interpret the `*`, so that my target would be the command below?

```
*/2 * * * * cd /myDirectory/ && ./myScript.sh
```

The use case would be:

```
bash$ APPLICATION_DIRECTORY="/myDirectory"
bash$ FULL_CRONTAB="*/2 * * * * cd ${APPLICATION_DIRECTORY}/ && ./myScript.sh"
bash$ echo ${FULL_CRONTAB}
```

On my terminal, the third command above outputs something like this:

```
*/2 -ltr (...list of all the files and folders in the current directory...) cd /myDirectory/ && ./myScript.sh
```

Comment: @Aaron as I said in my question, I tried both your suggestions and none of them works, the wildcard still expands.

Comment: Sorry I answered a bit too quickly. You need quotes in your second echo's argument ; see [here](https://ideone.com/EtDzfr)

Comment: @Aaron true, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to enclose your `FULL_CRONTAB` variable in double-quotes as below when using it, to prevent globbing :

```
"$FULL_CRONTAB"
```